# Apps script binding filter control to chart that uses setDataSourceUrl

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I am using Charts service in Google Apps Script. With [issue 1304](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1304) fixed, I am able to bind my charts to a Google Spreadsheet using setDataSourceUrl. In this way, I was able to embed [SQL-like queries](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) in the datasource url. Is it possible to bind filter controls (CategoryFilter, NumberRangeFilter etc.) to datasource url as well? My filter is not working when it is bound to a chart that uses setDataSourceUrl.

```
 var lineFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
  .setFilterColumnIndex(1)
  .build();

 var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
 .setDataSourceUrl(url) 
 .build();

 var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
 //not using setDataTable() because my chart is using setDataSourceUrl
 .bind([lineFilter], [pieChart])
 .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dashboards you need to ensure that you don't set any data sources on your charts individually, as they should be pulling the data from the dashboard. Unfortunately the DashboardPanel doesn't accept a data source URL at the moment, just a DataTable. Please file a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) if you'd like data source URLs to be supported.

Comment: Thank you Eric! I have entered [issue 1807](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1807)